# Unable to run single file executable dotnet application on 64-bit ARM machine

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I'm trying to run a .NET Core 3 executable on a 64-bit ARM machine. The Pine64 to be exact. I'm running the executable on 16.04 Ubuntu and using the `linux-arm` RID and it builds just fine but when trying to run it I get the error `No such file or directory` even though I'm looking at the file right in front of me.

Here is the command I'm running:

```
dotnet publish -c release -r linux-arm /p:PublishSingleFile=true -o $CWD/binaries/linux-arm -v q
```

If I build it without the single file then it runs perfectly fine but I need it to be a single file executable.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How exactly are you running it? Please include the exact and complete command and output. What do `pwd` and `find` say?

Comment: You should use the `linux-arm64` RID if you want to run on a 64-bit arm machine.

Comment: The command is literally just `./Bridge` and the output only says `No such file or directory`

Comment: That's what makes ot so difficult to debug because there is very limited information

Comment: What does `find` say? Is there a file named (exactly) `Bridge` (capitalization matters) in the current directory?

Comment: What if you run `chmod a+x Bridge` and then try again?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I tried it and got the same result.

Comment: I figured it out and posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer. So I was using the RID `linux-arm` which is fine if you are using a 32-bit device like a RaspberryPi. Pine64 is a 64-bit device and I was under the assumption that `linux-arm` was a magical RID that did both 64 and 32-bit because the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids) made it out that it was just that easy (at least that's how I interpreted it). Anyways, I used `linux-arm64` and BOOM it worked.